# Qt QTimeLine skips the first frame

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I am making a player move across the screen using QTimeLine to handle the animation/movement in the specified time.

In my player constructor:

```
timeLine = new QTimeLine(500);
timeLine->setFrameRange(1, 4);
timeLine->setCurveShape(QTimeLine::CurveShape::LinearCurve);
QObject::connect(timeLine, SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)), this, SLOT(animatedMove(int)));
```

I removed the animation stuff to just show the problem:

```
void PlayerSprite::animatedMove(int frame)
{
    qDebug() << "Frame: " << frame;
}
```

The timer is started in a slot which is called on key press:

```
void PlayerSprite::move(Direction direction)
{
    timeLine->start();
}
```

The output is:

```
GameView: Player is moving
Frame:  2
Frame:  3
Frame:  4
GameView: Player is moving
Frame:  1
Frame:  2
Frame:  3
Frame:  4
```

But it should be:

```
GameView: Player is moving
Frame:  1
Frame:  2
Frame:  3
Frame:  4
GameView: Player is moving
Frame:  1
Frame:  2
Frame:  3
Frame:  4
```

During each frame the player moves e.g. 2 steps. Therefore should move 4x2=8 steps... but on the first frame it only moves 6 steps meaning my character falls out of the game grid. I'm making an small 16 bit rpg ;)

**Is this because it is assumed that my player is already in it's first frame?**
if so can this be overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41610

The easiest work-around in your case is to set the current time of the time line to the duration on creation:

```
timeLine = new QTimeLine(500);
timeLine->setFrameRange(1, 4);
timeLine->setCurveShape(QTimeLine::CurveShape::LinearCurve);
// Add this line:
timeLine->setCurrentTime(timeLine->duration());
```

Comment: I was wondering for what reason it would behave like this. Didn't make much sense to me. Thanks so much for the easy work around. For future, how did you track this down? google didn't help at all.

Comment: My exact Google search term was "qt bug qtimeline".

Comment: Oh, OK. I should try something that simple next time ;)